# Android UI Tests crash but app runs fine

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, android-espresso

So I'm creating a sample project that's using this library https://github.com/OmerUygurOzer/Knit (Something I created) .

Problem is that the tests won't run with it. Not sure why. The app itself works fine. But when I run the tests, it errors out right on the line `Knit.init(this);` is called inside the Application class.

This is the logcat

```
02-13 20:46:20.471 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [interface com.omerozer.knit.InternalModel]
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:495)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at com.omerozer.knit.KnitClassLoader.getViewToPresenterConstructor(KnitClassLoader.java:64)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at com.omerozer.knit.KnitClassLoader.getViewToPresenterMap(KnitClassLoader.java:79)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at com.omerozer.knit.KnitClassLoader.<init>(KnitClassLoader.java:23)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at com.omerozer.knit.Knit.init(Knit.java:28)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at com.omerozer.knitmvpexample.MVPApp.onCreate(MVPApp.java:16)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:382)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
02-13 20:46:20.472 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
02-13 20:46:20.473 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample E/InstrumentationResultPrinter: Failed to mark test No Tests as finished after process crash
02-13 20:46:20.473 23727-23727/com.omerozer.knitmvpexample E/MonitoringInstr: Exception encountered by: com.omerozer.knitmvpexample.MVPApp@3a68f1a5. Dumping thread state to outputs and pining for the fjords.
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.omerozer.knit.KnitClassLoader.getViewToPresenterMap(KnitClassLoader.java:79)
                                                                                  at com.omerozer.knit.KnitClassLoader.<init>(KnitClassLoader.java:23)
                                                                                  at com.omerozer.knit.Knit.init(Knit.java:28)
                                                                                  at com.omerozer.knitmvpexample.MVPApp.onCreate(MVPApp.java:16)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
                                                                                  at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:382)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
```

Error message is this:

```
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to   java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It seems like the test environment can't find the init method?? which makes no sense to me.

Here's the gradle setup.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.omerozer.knitmvpexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.github.OmerUygurOzer.knit:knitlib:v1.0.2'
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor 'com.github.OmerUygurOzer.knit:knitprocessor:v1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.github.OmerUygurOzer.knit:knitlib:v1.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.OmerUygurOzer.knit:knitprocessor:v1.0.2'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what happens in Espresso.

Android JUnit runner runs in the same process in which the application runs. 
If you have a Runtime exception within your application(i.e [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)), it will break the whole  Instrumentation process.

I noticed this when I ran the application manually. It worked fine, when running instrumentation tests BUT, at some point, Instrumentation just crashed.

After further investigation I have noticed that there was a [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) within a module we're using in our app.

If you want to avoid the situation in which your Instrumentation crashes, you can use [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#using-android-test-orchestrator) (check out the presentation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pK7W5npkhho&t=1242s)). Running your tests this way, you will have isolated crashes.

If you can fix your critical exceptions happening in your code, just do it :-)